# Finding an element via xpath by index number of an element in a table

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, indexing

I am trying to find an element via index number in Python Selenium. The element has the following xpath;

```
/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[9]
```

I have also included the below image of the element I want.

Element I want:
[image: Element I want]

I am able to find the element via normal xpath, but I want to do this in a loop 10,000 times.

I was wondering if there is a way to find the element using its index number. Here is the code I have for it, for just index value 5, but it is not working.

```
Fund_click.append (driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='app']/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/[div/@index='5']"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your snapshot you can try this way to see if you get any difference.I have consider to attribute claas & Index.

```
for i in range(1,10000):    
   print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='tg-row tg-level-0 tg-even tg-focused']" and "//div[@index='" + str(i) + "']"))
```

If you want use index number then just try below code.But i am not sure you are able to identify elements only using index so better to try 1st option above.

```
for i in range(1,10000):
   print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@index='" + str(i) + "']"))
```

Comment: Thank you Kajal, I have put in the line of code you first suggested. However when I run my code it seems to select other parts of the table. Here is the new line
   
                                                                                                                   Fund_click.append (driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//div[@class='tg-row tg-level-0 tg-even']" or "//div[@class='tg-row tg-level-0 tg-odd']") and "//div[@index='" + str(i) + "']"))                                

Is there a way I could make it more exact?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I have coded best of your snapshot.can you please post html you want to get the xpath?

Comment: I'm sorry, You mean the link to the website with the html code inside? Unfortunately the website is via login. Is there a way I could forward you the login info in a place that is not public?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below xpath to confirm, you can able to locate all the elements or not? If the page is loaded fully then you should see all the matches (Inspect manually).

```
//div[@id='app']//div[contains(@class, 'tg-row')]
```

You can fetch and store all the elements by using `driver.find_elements_by_xpath()` method with the help of above xpath locator so that you can avoid iterating through element index each time. Try the below code :

```
# Fetching and storing all the matches
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='app']//div[contains(@class, 'tg-row')]");
for element in elements:
    # printing the index numbers to confirm it has fetched or not?
    print(element.get_attribute('index'))
```

Try to give some delay before fetching if the element is present and if you get `NoSuchElementException` or check for `frame/iframe`.

If all the elements are not visible, you many need to perform some scroll operations.

If the above mentioned method doesn't work then you can try the below xpaths to identify that element based on index/matching index numbers and you can proceed with your approach.

> (//div[@id='app']//div[contains(@class, 'tg-row')])[matching index]

or

> //div[@id='app']//div[contains(@class, 'tg-row') and @index='provide
>   index number here']

or

> //div[contains(@class, 'tg-row') and @index='provide index number
>   here']

or

> //div[@index='provide index number here']

or

> (//div[contains(@class, 'tg-row')])[provide matching index number
>   here]

I hope it helps...